# Counting number of accurate digits in approximation against the true value

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, char, floating-accuracy

I have created code that does a Newton's Method approximation.  It prints in a table-like format the approximation at each step and the associated error.  I want to add a column that shows an integer value that represents the number of correct digits in approximation against the true value.

I am attempting to convert each cell of approximation into a string and counting how many digits are accurate. Example, approx. = 3.14555, true = 3.1555. The number of accurate digits will be 2.  Although I have this idea in my head, I am doing it all wrong in my code below.  Do you know how to create a proper loop to achieve this?  I have less than a year of MATLAB experience; my mental toolbox is limited.

```
% Program Code of Newton's Method to find root
% This program will not produce a result if initial guess is too far from
% true value
clear;clc;format('long','g')
% Can work for various functions
%FUNCTION: 2*x*log(x)-2*log(x)*x^(3)+2*x^(2)*log(x)-x^(2)+1
%INTIAL GUESS: .01
%ERROR: 1.e-8
a=input('Enter the function in the form of variable x:','s');
x(1)=input('Enter Initial Guess:');
error=input('Enter allowed Error:');
% Passing through the function and calculating the derivative
f=inline(a);
dif=diff(str2sym(a));
d=inline(dif);
% Looping through Newton's Method
for i=1:100
x(i+1)=x(i)-((f(x(i))/d(x(i))));
err(i)=abs(x(i+1)-x(i));
% The loop is broken if acceptable error magnitude is reached 
if err(i)<error
break
end
end
root=x(i);
Root = (x(:,1:(end-1)))';
Error = err';

disp('The final approximation is:')
disp(root)
%BELOW IS ALL WRONG, I AM TRYING TO ADD A COLUMN TO 'table' 
%THAT SHOWS HOW MANY DIGITS IN APPROXIMATION IS ACCURATE
iter = 0;
y = zeros(1,length(x)); 
plot(x,y,'+')
zero1 = ('0.327967785331818'); %ACTUAL VALUE
for i = 1:length(Root)
    chr = mat2str(Root(i))
    for j = 1:length(chr(i))
        if chr(i)~=zero1(i)
            iter = 0;
            return
        elseif chr(i)==zero1(i)
            iter = iter + 1;
            acc(i) = iter
        end

    end

end
table(Root, Error)   %ADD ACCURACY COLUMN HERE
```

Comment: Why not use `log10` and the difference between the exact and approximate values? Notice that `log10(abs(3.14555-3.1555))=-2.0022`.

Comment: @David That is clever! I will try.

Comment: @David `>> log10(abs(0.32796778533175-0.263838689314425))
ans = -1.19294488198288` I don't think this is going to work out. This should be 0.

Comment: @PattyWatty27 its 1 because the difference numerically between them is less than 1. In your case then you want 0.19999 vs 0.200001 to be 0, but 0.19999 vs 0.1 to be 1? This is not very mathematical (and will make you confused, particularly if you are doing optimization.)

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is so true.  I did not think about that!  Maybe I should focus on error magnitude.

Comment: Instead of `log10(abs(x-y))`, you could consider `log10(abs(1-x/y))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like multiplying both numbers by powers of 10 and then flooring them until the answers are no longer equal:

```
approx=3.14555;
truth=3.1555;
approx1=0;
truth1=0;
i=0;
while approx1==truth1
   approx1=floor(approx*10^i);
   truth1=floor(truth*10^i);
   i=i+1;
end
acc=i-1;
```